# Relative Date calculation off

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to calculate dates relative to a certain date, but Im getting some very unusual responses. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I am US EST if it matters.

```
 <?php

        $firstweek_firsttime = date('D M j', strtotime("June 2016 first Sunday"));//June 19th 2016
        $firstweek_lasttime = date('D M j', strtotime("June 2016 second Saturday"));

    $ret=array(
        "Session #1. The week of ".$firstweek_firsttime." to ".$firstweek_lasttime." - ",
        "Session #2. The week of ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime next Sunday"))." to ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_lasttime next Saturday"))." - ",
        "Session #3. The week of ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime +10 day"))." to ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_lasttime +10 day"))." - "
        );


        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($ret as $wk)
        {
        ?>
            <li><?php echo($wk);?></li>
        <?php           
        }
?>
```

What I am getting:

```
The week of Sun Jun 19 to Sat Jun 18 -
The week of Thu Jan 1 to Thu Jan 1 -
The week of Wed Jul 1 to Tue Jun 30 -
```

Goal:

```
The week of Sun Jun 19 to Sat Jun 25 - 
The week of Sun Jun 26 to Sat Jul 2 - 
The week of Sun Jul 3 to Sat Jul 9 -
```

Comment: once check the calendar, you expected output is wrong

Comment: The dates expected are for 2016, not the current year, as shown in the first part of the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

Where "you" are has no bearing on your dates unless you set your timezone.
The date/time is set based on the server location.

<strike>It's a bit cumbersome, if I can find a better method I'll update my answer.</strike>

**UPDATE**

`strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime");` is the equivalent of writing `strtotime("Sun Jun 5");`will output 1433635200 (which, as of today, is actually Sun Jun 7 2015 00:00:00) because no year is indicated, the server defaults to the current year

`strtotime("next sunday");` will output 1441497600 (which, as of today, is equal to Sun Sep 6 2015 00:00:00
but
`strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime next sunday");` is invalid markup and will output nothing
so, since the timestamp is empty the date is automatically set to Jan 1, 1970

The same goes for `strtotime("$firstweek_lasttime next Saturday")`

`strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime +10 days")` is the same as `strtotime("Sun Jun 5 +10 days")`
without a Year the server defaults to the current year and writes it as `strtotime("Sun Jun 7 2015 +10 days")` because June 7 is the first Sunday for June in 2015
The same goes for `strtotime("$firstweek_lasttime +10 day")`

All that being said... the simple solution to your question is adding the year to your date format for $firstweek_firsttime and $firstweek_lasttime. This will keep your date in the year that you expect like so...

```
<?php

    $firstweek_firsttime = date('D M j Y', strtotime("June 2016 first Sunday")); // Sun Jun 5 2016
    $firstweek_lasttime = date('D M j Y', strtotime("June 2016 second Saturday"));
```

If you don't want to output the year to the browser simply change your first array item to...
`"Session #1. The week of ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_firsttime"))." to ".date('D M j', strtotime("$firstweek_lasttime"))." - ",`

**Reference**

[modify date](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: This looks interesting. I would really like to know what I did wrong however. Can you explain why I didnt get what I expected?